# Easier way? Azure Websites, Application logging asp.net

Tags: asp.net, azure, logging

When I get a call there was an error in our web application when running on a windows server I would simply go to Windows Logs and scroll down the application logs and find the Warning. Easy to read and made it quick to solve the problem.

Now I'm testing out Azure Websites to run asp.net applications and i'm racking my brain trying to figure out how to have the same kind of quick error find a fix process.

Viewing the application logging in Azure's application diagnostics is utterly useless.
It would take me forever to dig through those logs. rewriting the application to handle errors differently is not an option for me.

So who else is having this problem? any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to offload your error logs to a separate service like [Raygun](http://raygun.io). This will result in a (small) monthly fee but is a 5 minute setup and you are good to go.

Otherwise you can go and use [Log4net to log your error to the blob storage](http://blog.tylerdoerksen.com/2012/04/15/logging-in-azure-part-1/) but then you will have to poll that one for your logs.

Comment: Thanks Mark, Its a little pricey tho for smaller sites. Wish Azure would come up with a better way of handling logs.

Answer (score 0):

Try the **Azure Website Log Browser** site extension, you can install it from the new Azure Portal on your website (as a site extension) and it makes it easier to view all of your logs.

Read more about it [here](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/06/azure-website-logging/).